Are there any recommended books for self-study of lattice quantum chromodynamics?
I am a graduate student now. Because of my poor foundation, I don’t understand a lot of what the professor says in class. Although I can ask the professor, he is very busy and I have too many questions. So I would like to ask you to recommend a book that is friendly to beginners and provides detailed derivations of lattice quantum chromodynamics.
Thank you very much
